# ggtree plotting area not big enough

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioconductor, phylogeny, ggtree

I am trying to plot a circular phylogenetic tree with bootstrap labeled nodes and user defined/colored tip labels. I got the bootstrap results and labels to work properly, but somehow I just couldn't fully draw the plot in my graphic device. There were always labels (which radiated away from the center of the circular phylo tree) missing portions of themselves. The only way was to set the tip label size to be very very small.

The DNAbin file, on which the distance matrix and bootstrap were based, consists of 82 strains of microbial data (812aa). Tip label was colored based on a separate attribute file.

```
dna_b<-read.dna("filename.txt", format="fasta")
dist.b<-dist.dna(dna_b)
tree_b<-nj(dist.b)
bp_b<-boot.phylo(tree_b, dna_b, B=1000, function(xx) nj(dist.dna<xx)))
tree_b2<-apeBoot(tree_b, bp_b)
phylo_b<-ggtree(tree_b2, layout='circular', size=0.02, branch.length = "none")+geom_text2(aes(label=bootstrap), size = 2)+geom_tiplab(aes(angle=angle))
#I changed the tiplab to original so using user defined attribute data was not required (the next line).
#phylo_b<-phylo_b %<+% isolate_attr +geom_tiplab(aes(color=tr_level,angle=angle),size=1)
phylo_b+theme(legend.position = "right", legend.text = element_text(size=3))+guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3)))
```

I tried setting new graphic devices with bigger width and height but to no avail. Adjusting the margin didn't work either. By setting the tiplab size to smaller than 0.05 I could get the full plot, but that's really not optimal. Could really appreciate some help here.

Session info:

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                              
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[8] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggtree_1.6.11       ggplot2_2.2.1       S4Vectors_0.12.2   
[4] BiocGenerics_0.20.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.11     lattice_0.20-35  ape_4.1          tidyr_0.6.3     
 [5] digest_0.6.12    grid_3.3.3       plyr_1.8.4       jsonlite_1.5    
 [9] nlme_3.1-131     gtable_0.2.0     magrittr_1.5     scales_0.4.1    
[13] rlang_0.1.1      lazyeval_0.2.0   labeling_0.3     tools_3.3.3     
[17] munsell_0.4.3    colorspace_1.3-2 tibble_1.3.3
```

Rstudio version 1.0.136

Revised:
As pointed out earlier, data should have been provided to reproduce the problem. I am attaching part of the data here, full data is too big. I tried using stringi command to randomly generate dna sequences, but random sequences often result in NaNs in the dist file. The following data was directly copied from the txt file referenced in the first line of code, with part of the name redacted~

Fasta Data (b):

```
>Bacillus_somenameherethatsverylone_R2_1_anothernumber  
AACTACGCTCGCGTATCGGATTATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTTCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGAGACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCATGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATATGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGAAGTTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGAAAACTCTAGAGATAGAGCTTCTCCTTCGGGAGCAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCATCATTAAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGACGGTACAAAGAGCTGCAAGACCGCGAGGTGGAGCTAATCTCATAAAACCGTTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCTGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGTCGGTGGGGTAACCTTTATGGAGCCAGCCGCCTAAGTGGGACAGATGATTGGGGTGAAGTCGTACAAGGTACCCAAA

>Bacillus_sp._R2_8_anothernumber    
TTACTATGATAGCGTGTCGGATTATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTCCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGGAACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCAAGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATTTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGCAGCTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGACAACCCTAGAGATAGGGCTTTCCCCTTCGGGGGACAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCAGCATTCAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGATGGTACAAAGGGCTGCACACCTGCGAAGGTAAGCGAATCCCATAAAGCCATTCTCAGTTCGGATTGCAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTGCATGAGCCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAGCACCCGAAGTCGTGACGTAACCTTCATGGAGCCAGTCAGCCTATGTGGGACAGATGATTGGGGTGAGTCGTACCAAAGTAAACACA

>Bacillus_sp._R2_9_anothernumber
GTTACCCCTGACGTGTCGGATATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTCCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGGAACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCAAGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATTTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGCAGCTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGACAACCCTAGAGATAGGGCTTTCCCCTTCGGGGGACAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCAGCATTCAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGATGGTACAAAGGGCTGCAAACCTGCGAAGGTAAGCGAATCCCATAAAGCCATTCTCAGTTCGGATTGCAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTGCATGAAGCCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGTCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGTCGGTGAGGTAACCTTCATGTAGTCAGCCGCCTATGTGGGACAGATGATTGGGGTGAGTCGTACCAAGGAAAGCCAGC

>Bacillus_someotherlongname_R2_21_anothernumber
TTACTTTTCTACGTATCGGATATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTTCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGAGACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCATGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATATGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGAAGTTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGAAAACTCTAGAGATAGAGCTTCTCCTTCGGGAGCAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCATCATTAAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGACGGTACAAAGAGCTGCAAGACCGCGAGGTGGAGCTAATCTCATAAAACCGTTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCTGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGTCGGTGGGGTAACCTTTATGGAGCCAGCCGCCTATGTGGGACAGATGATTGGGGTGAAGTCGTACCAAGGTAGCCCATA

>Bacillus_sp._R2_42_anothernumber   
ATTCTTTCTCGCGTGTCGGATATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTCCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGGAACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCAAGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATTTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGCAGCTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGACAACCCTAGAGATAGGGCTTTCCCCTTCGGGGGACAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCAGCATTCAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGATGGTACAAAGGGCTGCAAACCTGCGAAGGTAAGCGAATCCCATAAAGCCATTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGTCGGTGAGGTAACCTTTATGGAGCCAGCCGCCTAAAGTGGGACAGATGATTGGGGTGAAGTCGTACCACAGGTTAACCA

>Bacillus_sp._R2_75_anothernumber   
TCTTCAACCGCGTGTCGGATATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTCCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGGAACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCAAGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATTTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCGAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGCAGCTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTTTTGCCCTCCCTAGAGATAGGGACTTCCCTTCGGGGACAAAAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCAGCATTTAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGATGGTACAAAGAGCTGCAAACCCGCGAGGGTAAGCGAATCTCATAAAGCCATTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGTGGATCAGCATGCCACGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGTCGGTGAGGTAACCGCAAGGAGCCAGCCGCCTAAAGTGGGACAGATGATTGGGGTGAGTCGACACAGGGGAAACCCA

>Bacillus_sp._R2_106_anothernumber
GCGGATATGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTCCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGGAACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCAAGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATTTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGCAGCTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGACAACCCTAGAGATAGGGCGTTCCCCTTCGGGGGACAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCAGCATTTAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGGATGGTACAAAAGGGCTGCAAACCTGCGAAGGTAAGCGAATCCCATAAAGCCATTCTCAGTTCGGGATTGTAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCCGCCCCGTCACACCACGAGAAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAAGTCGGGTGAGGTAACCCTTTTATGG

>Bacillus_somelongnameagain_R2_115_anothernumber
GTCGAATTATGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTTCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGAGACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCATGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATATGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGAAGTTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGAAAACTCTAGAGATAGAGCTTCTCCTTCGGGAGCAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCATCATTAAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGACGGTACAAAGAGCTGCAAGACCGCGAGGTGGAGCTAATCTCATAAAACCGTTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCTGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGTCTTGTACAT

>Bacillus_sp._R2_116_anothernumber  
AAAACAGTGTTTGCTTTTTATTCAGATATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTTCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGAGACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCATGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATATGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGAAGTTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGAAAACCCTAGAGATAGGGCTTCTCCTTCGGGAGCAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCATCATTAAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGACGGTACAAAGAGCTGCAAGACCGCGAGGTGGAGCTAATCTCATAAAACCGTTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCTGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGTCGGTGGGGTAACTTTATGGAGCCAGCCGCCTAAGTGGGACAGATGATTGGGGTGAAGTCGTACCAAGGTAAGCCAT

>Bacillus_sp._R3_1_anothernumber    
GTAGGATATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTCCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGGAACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCAAGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATTTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGCAGCTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGACAACCCTAGAGATAGGGCGTTCCCCTTCGGGGGACAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCAGCATTCAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGATGGTACAAAGGGCTGCAAACCTGCGAAGGTAAGCGAATCCCATAAAAGCCATTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGGCTGCAAACTCGCCTACATGAAAGCCGGAAATCGCTAGTTATTCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTTGAATACGTTCCCCGGGCCTTGTAACACACCCGCCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTTGTAACACCCGAAAGTCGGTGGAGGGTAACCCTTTTTATTG

>Bacillus_cereus_R3_2_anothernumber
GTAAGCATTTGGATGCATCTGGAATCGGTATATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTTCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGAGACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCATGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATATGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGAAGTTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGAAAACCCTAGAGATAGGGCTTCTCCTTCGGGAGCAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCATCATTAAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGACGGTACAAAGAGCTGCAAGACCGCGAGGTGGAGCTAATCTCATAAAACCGTTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCTGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGTCGGTGGGGTAACCTTTTATGGAGCCAGCCGCCTAAAGTGGGACAGATGATTGGGGGTGAAGTCGTAACAAGGGTAGCC

>Bacillus_sp._R3_19_anothernumber
AACGGTTCAGCCACGTGTCGGATATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTCCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGGAACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCAAGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATTTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGCAGCTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGACAACCCTAGAGATAGGGCGTTCCCCTTCGGGGGACAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCAGCATTCAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGATGGTACAAAGGGCTGCAAACCTGCGAAGGTAAGCGAATCCCATAAAGCCATTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGTCGGTGAGGTAACCTTTATGGAGCCAGCCGCCTAAGTGGGACAGATGATTGGGGTGAAGTCGTACAACAGGAGGTAACA

>Bacillus_sp._R3_20_anothernumber
GGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTCCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGGAACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCAAGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATTTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGCAGCTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGACAACCCTAGAGATAGGGCGTTCCCCTTCGGGGGACAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCAGCATTCAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGATGGTACAAAAGGGCTGCAAACCTGCGAAGGTAAGCGAATCCCATAAAAGCCATTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCCCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAAATAACGTTCCCGGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAAACAACCCGAAAGTCGGGTGAGGTAACCCTTTATGGGAGCCAGCCGCCTTAAAGGTGGAACAGATGAATTGGGGTGAAAGTCGTAACAAGGGTAAGCCAA

>Bacillus_sp._R3_22_anothernumber
TCGGTACACTCACGTGTCGGATATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTCCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGGAACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCAAGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATTTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGCAGCTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGACAACCCTAGAGATAGGGCGTTCCCCTTCGGGGGACAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCAGCATTCAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGATGGTACAAAGGGCTGCAAACCTGCGAAGGTAAGCGAATCCCATAAAGCCATTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGTCGGTGAGGTAACCTTTATGGAGCCAGCCGCCTAAGGGGGGACAGATGATTGGGGTGAAGTCGACAACAAAGGGTATAACA

>Bacillus_sp._R3_74_anothernumber
AGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTTCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGAGACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCATGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATATGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGAAGTTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGAAAACTCTAGAGATAGAGCTTCTCCTTCGGGAGCAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCATCATTAAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGACGGTACAAAGAGCTGCAAGACCGCGAGGTGGAGCTAATCTCATAAAACCGTTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCTGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGACCTTGTACACACCGCTCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTTGTTACTACCCGAAAGTCGGTGGGGGTAACCTTTATGGGAGTCAGGCCGCCTTAAGGTGGGACAGAATGATTGGGGGGTGAAAGTTCGTTAACCAAGGGTTAGCCAAATT

>Bacillus_sp._R3_76_anothernumber
AACACGTGACGTGTCGGATATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTCCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGGAACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCAAGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATTTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGCAGCTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGACAACCCTAGAGATAGGGCGTTCCCCTTCGGGGGACAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCAGCATTCAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGATGGTACAAAGGGCTGCAAACCTGCGAAGGTAAGCGAATCCCATAAAGCCATTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCCGGATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGTCGGTGAGGTAACCTTTATGGAGCCAGCCGCCTAAGTGGACAGATGATGGGGTGAGCTAC

>Bacillus_sp._R3_89_anothernumber
TCGTCTACCGCACGTGTCGGATATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTCCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGGAACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCAAGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATTTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGCAGCTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGACAACCCTAGAGATAGGGCGTTCCCCTTCGGGGGACAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCAGCATTCAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGATGGTACAAAGGGCTGCAAACCTGCGAAGGTAAGCGAATCCCATAAAGCCATTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGTCGGTGAGGTAACCTTTATGGAGCCAGCCGCCTAAGGTGGGACAGATGATTGGGGTGAAGTCGACACA

>Bacillus_sp._R4_18_anothernumber
GGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTTCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGAGACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCATGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATATGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGAAGTTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGAAAACTCTAGAGATAGAGCTTCTCCTTCGGGAGCAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCATCATTAAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGACGGTACAAAGAGCTGCAAGACCGCGAGGTGGAGCTAATCTCATAAAACCGTTCTCAGTTTCGGATTGTGGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCTGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGAGACCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTACACCCGAAGTCGGTGGAGTAACCCTTTATGGAGTCCAGCGCCTAAGTGGGACAGATGATTGGGGGTGAAGTCGTACCAGTACCCATCT

>Bacillus_someotherlongname_R4_23_anothernumber
AGGTACAGTAGACGTATCGGATATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTTCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGAGACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCATGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATATGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGAAGTTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGAAAACTCTAGAGATAGAGCTTCTCCTTCGGGAGCAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCATCATTAAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGACGGTACAAAGAGCTGCAAGACCGCGAGGTGGAGCTAATCTCATAAAACCGTTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCTGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGTCGGTGGGGTAACTTTATGGAGCAGCCGCCTAAGGTGGGACAGATGATTGGGGTGAAGTCGTAACAAGGTAGCCA

>Bacillus_sp._R4_38_anothernumber
AAACTCTTTGTTTACTTATACCACGTGTCGGATATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTCCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGGAACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCACGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATGTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCGAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGCAGCTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTTTTGCCCTCCCTAGAGATAGGGACTTCCCTTCGGGGACAAAAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCAGCATTTAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGATGGTACAAAGAGCTGCGAACCCGCGAGGGTAAGCGAATCTCATAAAGCCATTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGTCGGTGAGGTAACCGCAAGGAGTCAGCCGCCTAAGTGGGACAGATGATTGGGGTGAAGTCGTACACAAGTAAAACT

>Bacillus_somelongname_R5_1_anothernumber
CGATATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTTCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGAGACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCATGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATATGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGAAGTTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGAAAACCCTAGAGATAGGGCTTCTCCTTCGGGAGCAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCATCATTAAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGACGGTACAAAGAGCTGCAAGACCGCGAGGTGGAGCTAATCTCATAAAACCGTTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCTGGGAACGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCACATGCCGCGGGGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTTGTTACACCCGAAATTCGGTGGGGTAACCTTCATGGGAGCCAGCCCGCCTAAGGGGGGACAGAATGATTGGGTGAAGTC

>Bacillus_sp._R5_6_anothernumber
TGAATAACAAACGACGTGTCGGATATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTCCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGGAACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCAAGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATTTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGCAGCTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGACAACCCTAGAGATAGGGCGTTCCCCTTCGGGGGACAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCAGCATTCAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGATGGTACAAAGGGCTGCAAACCTGCGAAGGTAAGCGAATCCCATAAAGCCATTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCTCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGTCGGTGAGGTAACCTTTATGGAGCCAGCCGCCTAAGGTGGGACAGATGATTGGGGTGAAGTCGTACAC

>Bacillus_sp._R5_8_anothernumber
TTAGGATATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTCCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGGAACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCAAGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATTTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGCAGCTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGACAACCCTAGAGATAGGGCGTTCCCCTTCGGGGGACAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCAGCATTCAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGATGGTACAAAGGGCTGCAAACCTGCGAAGGTAAGCGAATCCCATAAGCCATTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGTCGGTGAGGTAACCTTTATGGA

>Bacillus_sp._R5_10_anothernumber
TTACTTATGTGACGTGTCGGATTATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTCCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGGAACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCAAGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATTTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGCAGCTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGACAACCCTAGAGATAGGGCTTTCCCCTTCGGGGGACAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCAGCATTCAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGATGGTACAAAGGGCTGCAAACCTGCGAAGGTAAGCGAATCCCATAAGCCATTCTCAGTTCGGATTGCAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTGCATGAAGCCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGTCGGTGAGGTAACCTTTATGGAGCCAGCCGCCTAAGGGGGGACAGATGATTGGGGTGAAGTCGTACACAAGGTAAACTT

>Bacillus_somelongnamehere_R5_11_anothernumber
ATACTAACTTCTCACGTACGGATATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTTCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGAGACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGAAAGTGGAATTCCATGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATATGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTTTCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTAGAGGGTTTCCGCCCTTTAGTGCTGAAGTTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGCCGCAAGGCTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCTCTGAAAACTCTAGAGATAGAGCTTCTCCTTCGGGAGCAGAGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTGATCTTAGTTGCCATCATTAAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGTGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGACGGTACAAAGAGCTGCAAGACCGCGAGGTGGAGCTAATCTCATAAAACCGTTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCTGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCATCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGTCGGTGGGGTAACCTTTATGGAGCCAGCCGCCTAAGTGGGACAGATGATTGGGGTGAAGTCGTACAAGGGTAGCCATAAC

>Bacillus_longnamehere_R5_12_anothernumber
TACTTTCCCGCGTGTCGGATATTGGGCGTAAGCGCGCGCAGGTGGTTTCTTAAGTCTGATGTGAAAGCCCACGGCTCAACCGTGGAGGGTCATTGGAAACTGGGAAACTTGAGTGCAGAAGAGGATAGTGGAATTCCAAGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGAGATTTGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGACTATCTGGTCTGTAACTGACACTGAGGCGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGGATTAGATACCCTGGTAGTCCACGCCGTAAACGATGAGTGCTAAGTGTTGGGGGGTTTCCGCCCCTCAGTGCTGCAGCTAACGCATTAAGCACTCCGCCTGGGGAGTACGGTCGCAAGACTGAAACTCAAAGGAATTGACGGGGGCCCGCACAAGCGGTGGAGCATGTGGTTTAATTCGAAGCAACGCGAAGAACCTTACCAGGTCTTGACATCCCATTGACCACTGTAGAGATACAGTTTTCCCTTCGGGGACAACGGTGACAGGTGGTGCATGGTTGTCGTCAGCTCGTGTCGTGAGATGTTGGGTTAAGTCCCGCAACGAGCGCAACCCTTATTCTTAGTTGCCATCATTTAGTTGGGCACTCTAAGGAGACTGCCGGTGACAAACCGGAGGAAGGTGGGGATGACGTCAAATCATCATGCCCCTTATGACCTGGGCTACACACGTGCTACAATGGACGGTACAAACGGTTGCCAACCCGCGAGGGGGAGCTAATCCGATAAAACCGTTCTCAGTTCGGATTGTAGGCTGCAACTCGCCTACATGAAGCCGGAATCGCTAGTAATCGCGGATCAGCATGCCGCGGTGAATACGTTCCCGGGCCTTGTACACACCGCCCGTCACACCACGAGAGTTTGTAACACCCGAAGTCGGTGGGGTAACCTTTATGGAGCCAGCCGCCGAAGTGGGATAGATGATTGGGGTGAAGTCGTACCAAGGTACTAA
```

[image: Posting a plot without the user defined colors, the problems are similar]

Comment: There is nothing for us to go on here. No data, no plots. Are you plotting to a window or to a file? Can you use `ggsave` and play with the dimensions, dpi, and scale setting?

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing that out, pardon me for not providing the info required. I have revised the question to contain part of the original fasta sequence and the full code so that the problem is at least partly reproducible. I was plotting to a window at the time, but no matter what kind of graphic device I used, or dimensions I changed, the exported/saved plot still came out similar to the console displayed one, with tiplabs partly gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Axeman mentioned in his comment, with `ggsave` you could adjust dimensions. You could combine this with adjusting for label size as well.

```
library(ggtree)
library(ape)

# Generate a random tree
set.seed(2018)
my_labels <- paste(paste(LETTERS, collapse = ""), 1:20) # generate long labels
tree <- ape::rcoal(n = 20, tip.label = my_labels)

# plot the tree
ggtree(tr = tree, layout = 'circular') +
  geom_tiplab(size = 2, aes(angle = angle))

# Save as PDF and force a 'huge' size plot
ggsave("assets/test.pdf", width = 50, height = 50, units = "cm", limitsize = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems like a plausible workaround. I guess the problem comes naturally when trying to fit so many sequences (and such long names) in a circular tree.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried manually adjusting with `xlim(xmin, xmax)`?

Example:

`tree <- rtree(10)
ggtree(tree) + xlim(-10, 10)`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, RaphiS, sorry it took so long to respond. Adjusting the limits didn't really work, if the labels were long enough they would still protrude outside of the drawing region. Right now @Valentin's solution seems like a working plan.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue too and have used both the `ggsave()` answer provided by Valentin and the `xlim()` answer provided by RaphiS. `ggsave()` will work but we may not want to make such a huge plot, in which case `xlim()` would be preferable.

I would like to point out that people need to play around with the `xlim()` values and not just try (-10,10) or (0,0.06) (from https://support.bioconductor.org/p/72398/) and give up if they get an error. The `xlim()` values needed also depend on your tree and the tree layout. For reference, for my tree with 261 nodes, for a normal vertical layout tree with branch lengths I used `xlim(0,1)`, and for the same tree with `layout = "circular"` and `branch.length = "none"` I used `xlim(0,36)`. You can also play with `plot.margin()` in tandem with `xlim()`.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the size of the plot manually with either  `+ xlim(NA, 24)` and adjust the size as you prefer

or `+ theme(plot.margin = unit(c(14,8,14,8), "mm"))`

Adjust the font in tip labelling with `+ geom_tiplab(size =3)` and adjust the size as you want.

e.g.

```
tree2 <- tree1+ xlim(NA, 24)
#or
tree2 <- tree1 + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(14,8,14,8), "mm"))

#In this case 14mm, 8mm, 14mm and 8mm can be your starting settings. By either increasing or reducing individual settings of margins as you like till you get an optimised plot. 

tree2 <- tree2 + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(10,8,10,8), "mm"))

tree2 <- tree2 + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(20,10,20,10), "mm"))
tree2 <- tree2 + geom_tiplab(size =3)#to choose your preferred font size of the tip labels
```

Best wishes,

Evans